# How to communicate between different domain iframe and the parent like Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, iframe, reporting-services

How we trigger the angular function and pass the Id Parameter from different domain iframe (SSRS Report -- Microsoft).

I am using the `postMessage` API for communicating but it is still not working.

Below is the another domain iframe (SSRS Report) postmessage function

```
<a tabindex="1" href="javascript:void(window.parent.postMessage(%7Bfoo:%22foo%22%7D));" target="_top"><div>21866</div></a
```

using javascript:void  and passing the Post Message.

my angular-4 Code.

```
@HostListener("window:message",["$event"]) fetchProviderId($event:MessageEvent) {
    if ($event.origin !== " ")
        return;
    console.log($event.data);
}
```

Please help. I have seen many links but its not working for me.